# Prove the following integral identity

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Does any one have any idea on how to prove the following:

$$\int_0^Sf(z)\,\mathrm{d}z+a\int_0^Sf(z)\left(\int_0^zf(z_1)\,\mathrm{d}z_1\right)\,\mathrm{d}z+a^2\int_0^Sf(z)\left[\int_0^zf(z_1)\left(\int_0^{z_1}f(z_2)\,\mathrm{d}z_2\right)\,\mathrm{d}z_1\right]\,\mathrm{d}z+\cdots=\frac{1}{a}\left[e^{a\int_0^Sf(z)\,\mathrm{d}z}-1\right]$$

Comment: Is the sum infinite? Are there hypothesis on $f$?

Comment: Yes, the sum is infinite. $f$ is real arbitrary smooth and continuous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the sum be $y(s)$ and $F'(s)=f(s)$.

Assume converging, we have

\begin{align*}
  y(s) &= \int_{0}^{s} f(t)[1+ay(t)]\, dt \\
  y'(s) &= f(s)[1+ay(s)] \\
  y'(s)-af(s)y(s) &= f(s) \\
  I(s) &=
  \exp \left[-\int a f(s)ds \right]
  \tag{integrating factor} \\
  &= e^{-a F(s)} \\
  I(s) y(s) &= \int f(s) I(s) ds \\
  e^{-aF(s)} y(s) &= \int e^{-aF(s)} f(s) ds \\
  &= \int e^{-aF(s)} dF(s) \\
  &= -\frac{1}{a} e^{-aF(s)}+k \\
  y(s) &= ke^{aF(s)}-\frac{1}{a} \\
  y(0) &= 0 \\
  k &= \frac{1}{a} e^{-aF(0)} \\
  y(s) &=
  \frac{1}{a}
  \left \{
    e^{a[F(s)-F(0)]}-1
  \right \} \\
  &=\frac{1}{a}
  \left \{ \exp \left[ a\int_{0}^{s} f(t)\, dt \right]-1 \right \} \\
\end{align*}